# Returning reference to potentially changing data in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, functor

In C++, is it a good idea to return a constant reference to data that may change?  For instance, suppose you have a functor:

```
template<class T>
struct f {
  f(const T& init) data{init} {}
  const T& operator() () { return ++data; }
private:
  T data;
};
```

As an example of my concerns, could a function take the address of the returned data?  This would give a nasty surprise later when the value was changed "behind the client's back."  (Or does the returned reference count as an rvalue, making finding its address illegal?)  What other issues might I, or other clients, run into down the road?

tl;dr:  Is the above functor a good idea?

Comment: As you've mentioned, its terribly dangerous to return a const ref to a piece of data that can be modified. Why would you want to do this? Do you have a specific use-case in mind?

Comment: Potentially, I would use it to build an iterator with a state.  Since it's inefficient (O(log n)) to build the entire return value for `iterator::operator*()` every time, I'm considering storing the prebuilt value in the iterator, which, while somewhat expensive compared to a "cheap" iterator that has just a pointer, would have constant-time updates for the stored data.  The fun part is, what happens when clients advance the iterator and expect their old return value from `iterator::operator*()` to be there?  So, can that happen, and should it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> could a function take the address of the returned data?

Yes. i.e. `const int* ptr = &my_f();` Please note that you'll still safe from having the client inadvertently modifying the data and break your class invariants, as you cannot modify the data pointed by a `const int*`, except if you start outwitting the type system and cast it to an `int*`.

> This would give a nasty surprise later when the value was changed "behind the client's back."

The client would know based from the function's signature alone that the function returns a reference. If clients want to have a copy of their own for them to modify or to prevent it from being modified by your class, then he can just do `int my_own_copy = my_f();`, and he gets a copy.

> Or does it count as an rvalue, making finding its address illegal?

Unless you do something like `const int& operator() () { return data++; /* Note: postfix */ }`, then the client would be safe from having to illegally reference invalid data.

> What other issues might I, or other clients, run into down the road?

One common problem would be that the lifetime of the client's reference would exceed the lifetime of the object that has the referenced data. Still, this is still true for other references, and thus the client doesn't have to learn another guideline for their references to remain valid.

> tl;dr: Is the above functor a good idea?

**tl;dr:** Yes. As mentioned above, the client could still get a copy if he needs it, or he may opt to have a reference to the data if he doesn't want to incur the cost of copying potentially large data.

Comment: Informative, thanks.  If I were to return by value, would that get optimized away by compilers that can perform return value elision, or some other clever optimization that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty Return by value only when you really need to return by value for the sake of correctness (e.g. returning a local variable). For scenarios in which you can just safely return a const reference to data, then return a const reference. It's also helpful to heed the other answer's advise not to return by reference primitive types.

Comment: Ok, good rule of thumb.  I made a comment to my original question that explains my specific use-case in a bit more detail, if you're curious.

Answer (score 0):

For primitive types, returning by const reference does usually not really make sense - since the reference will be equally big (in terms of memory size), or might be even larger than the primitive type itself.

Also, consider the case where an instance of `struct f` gets deleted while a reference is still in use - it will refer to deleted data! That is never good and needs to be prevented.

Only for larger, user-defined types I would recommend to consider this pattern (where avoiding copying might give a performance advantage or can help maintain a small memory footprint), but then also only use it when you can guarantee that the object returning the reference will live longer or at least just as long than the object using the reference.

Regarding the caller being able to modify the value: Only taking the address of such an expression is not enough; the caller would also have to const-cast the reference to make it modifyable (check the referene for [const_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)). Except for some rare circumstances, the `const_cast` is very bad practice, and should therefore usually cause all alarm bells to ring during e.g. a review anyway. So that aspect is not something you'd have to consider too much.

Comment: Hmmm, I was worried that I'd get the first critique because I was using `int` as a simple example.  If I templatize `int` away, how does that change your answer?

Comment: not at all. I'm referring to both primitive and user defined types already